# How to restart A Sql Azure Instance?

Tags: sql, azure

How can I restart my SQL Azure Server ?

Is this possible ?

Comment: My first interaction with the sql genius MrDenny and he is telling me I'm dumb... #sadface

Comment: Maybe you should mention what the problem is, or why you want to restart it... there are other ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Well I can't connect entity framework to a SQL Azure instance. I believe that the issue is VS11 beta. There is a bug report about the exact issue I'm having. I am in the process of uninstalling vs11 beta and .net 4.5. I have high hopes.

Comment: @mrdenny is calling you no such thing. Windows Azure SQL Database is a shared resource, multi-tenant database service. You are provided with a connection string and full access to the database(s) that you provision, along with server- and database-level firewall settings, and the service takes care of everything else. Hence... no reason you'd need to restart the server (which equates to multiple *physical* servers: You don't have physical access to the servers directly.

Comment: If you can't connect, have you added a firewall rule to allow connections?

Comment: The issue was installation of vs2012 side by side with vs2010 on win7. 
My unit tests were failing because of a communication issue caused by this setup. It really had nothing to do with SQL Azure

Comment: @voretaq7 what's not real question about it? It's real but (unfortunately) impossible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262001/how-do-i-stop-and-start-a-sql-azure-database According to this it's possible.

Comment: @carles this question is five years old...

Comment: @Robotsushi well, I just thought to add more info in case someone arrives here and sees this. Sorry if it bothered you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.  There is no reason that you'd need to restart the SQL Azure instance.

Comment: Unless attempts to execute queries do not respond and do not time out. I'm sitting with a db that backs a website, attempts to update tables in the db with SSMS and with the web-based portal are spinning and spinning and not accomplishing anything. with on-prem I'd boot the sql instance and, failing that, re-boot the server and go about my day. Long-time azure user and this is a first.

Comment: And to follow up with resolution - closing down SSMS released enough /whatevers\ resources to return to operational state. SELECT statements worked fine - UPDATE statements locked the session when executed via CLI, while website-based UPDATE statements executed correctly.

Comment: Yes, we also had a slow queries problem and restarting the database was the only way to fix it.

Comment: The second part of this answer is unnecessary and presumptuous, and the first part is not very helpful.